# mvn clean package builds EAR with only META-INF

Tags: java, build, ejb, maven-3, ear

I'm trying to build a project (packaged as an ear) to be run on WebLogic. However, while the build (mvn clean package) is successful, the ear file contains only a META-INF folder with very few files within.

I'm not super-familiar with the project (or EJB), but it looks like an EJB project (I see EJBHome, EJBObject, EJBLocalObject).

Not really sure where to go from here - I've searched online and through other posts, but not much has come up. Even a point in the right direction would be useful.

**Build log:**

```
C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice>mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building reportservice 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ reportservice ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.8:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) @ reportservice ---
[INFO] Generating application.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ reportservice ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e.
build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.8:ear (default-ear) @ reportservice ---
[INFO] Could not find manifest file: C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\target\reportservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF - Generating one
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\target\reportservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.380 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-03T19:55:50-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/244M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Resulting EAR:**
[image]

**Resulting pom.xml (inside built ear)**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>reportservice</groupId>
  <artifactId>reportservice</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
</project>
```

**pom.xml from source**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>reportservice</groupId>
  <artifactId>reportservice</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>libs-release</name>
      <url>http://artifactory.gxsonline.net/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://artifactory.gxsonline.net/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>plugins-release</name>
      <url>http://artifactory.gxsonline.net/plugins-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://artifactory.gxsonline.net/plugins-snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\target</directory>
    <finalName>reportservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-ear</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>ear</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-generate-application-xml</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate-application-xml</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\LevineJ\Development\default-workspace\reportservice\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: show you project pom.xml

Comment: @sunysen - Just added the built and source pom.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Problem is that there are no dependencies to your ejb packaged jars..

Have a look at the following GitHub Repository:
https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/stackoverflow-1134894

there you can see clean a simple example how you should package a java ee application with maven.

**pom.xml of the ear project:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>myproject-application</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>MyProject - Application</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-web</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-business</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.example.myproject</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myproject-web</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>com.example.myproject</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myproject-business</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Properties in your parent pom.xml:**

```
<maven.ear.duplicateArtifactsBreakTheBuild>true</maven.ear.duplicateArtifactsBreakTheBuild>
<maven-ear-plugin.version>2.10</maven-ear-plugin.version>
```

**EAR Plugin configuration in the  section of your parent pom.xml:**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-ear-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
        <version>7</version>
        <!-- Die EAR Spezifikation sieht den *.ear/lib ordner als standard vor.
        dieser muss im application.xml nicht zusätzlich aufgelistet werden. -->
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <libraryDirectoryMode>NONE</libraryDirectoryMode>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```